# Cannot show childNodes from parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade in" role="dialog" style="display: block; padding-right: 13px;">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div id="modal-alert" class="alert hidden"></div>
                    <div id="modal-body-content"></div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
```

I want to show the childNodes which hold of the div `modal-body`.

I get the error when click on the anchor for open up my modal

```
$("a#showUser").on('click', function(evt) {
    var parentElement = document.getElementsByClassName('modal-body');
    console.log(parentElement);
    console.log(parentElement.childNodes[0]);
});
```

[image: Here error]

Comment: where is your `a#showUser` in html?

Comment: console.log(parentElement[0].childNodes[0]);

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementsByClassName('modal-body')` returns an Array of nodes, so you can't access `childNodes` on an array. Change it to something like this.

```
$("a#showUser").on('click',function(evt){
   var parentElements = document.getElementsByClassName('modal-body');
   console.log(parentElements);
   console.log(parentElements[0].childNodes[0]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the parent's children of the link which is clicked, then use the following since you are using jQuery.

```
$("a#showUser").on('click',function(evt){
      var parentElement = $(this).closest('.modal-body');
      console.log(parentElement);
      console.log(parentElement.children());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`.getElementsByClassName()` gives you an HTML collection, an array. You should indicate a single element in the collection. Try this:

```
var parentElement = document.getElementsByClassName('modal-body')[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `parentElement` as a variable name, because it's a native javascript property.

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns an array of elemnts so you should use

```
document.getElementsByClassName('modal-body')[0].childNodes[0]
```